# Python: Endless recursion when trying to find forks of forks of Github repositories

Tags: python-3.x, github, recursion, python-requests, fork

As a beginner learning Python 3 and how to use APIs, I'm trying to develop a simple script that takes a Github repository and *recursively* identifies all forks of all forks of said repository. The idea is to end up with a `list` type variable containing the forks (and information on the parent of those forks) (unless another variable type is better?) that I can export to a JSON file as an additional exercise.

Right now, I am using the Python 3 `requests` library and a combination of `for` and `while` loops (yes, I know `while = True` loops are dangerous, let me know if there's a better way).

Here's code with an example repository ([`OpenROV/openrov-software`](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software)) to find forks for with Github authentication token obfuscated:

```
import requests

#
# getting forks
#

# the starting repository to find forks for
username = "OpenROV"
repo = "openrov-software"
# fake Github auth token:
auth = ("ScroogeMcDuck", "fqo4p6xx6p2cgnwi3fakjotx7c46n5xcfzxpz3hz")

# initialise an empty list of forks
forks = list()

# Recursive function to find all forks of forks of a Github repository
def get_Github_forks(owner, repo, forks, auth=None, recurse=False):
    page_counter = 1
    request_output = list()
    print("Finding forks for repository: {}/{}".format(owner, repo))
    while True:
        print("Retrieving forks page {}".format(page_counter))
        request_string = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/forks?page={}".format(owner, repo, page_counter)
        print("Request string:", request_string)
        request_output = requests.get(request_string, auth = auth).json()
        for item in request_output:
            forks.append({"fork_owner": item["owner"]["login"], "fork_repo": item["name"], "created_at": item["created_at"], "forked_from_owner": owner, "forked_from_repo": repo})
        # Stop going to the next page of results if the current result is 0,
        # meaning we're already past the last page.
        if len(request_output) == 0:
            break
        # Otherwise, move on to the next page of results
        else:
            page_counter = page_counter + 1
    for fork in forks:
        get_Github_forks(owner=fork["fork_owner"], repo=fork["fork_repo"], forks=forks, auth=auth, recurse=True)

# find forks
get_Github_forks(owner=username, repo=repo, forks=forks, auth=auth, recurse=True)
```

When running this code, I see that it successfully identifies all forks of the parent/original repository (it has 179 forks), but it gets stuck repeating getting the first page of results for the first fork, namely `labimage/openrov-software`. Note that this first fork (`labimage/openrov-software`) doesn't actually have any forks. If I use the command `curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1"` in a terminal it shows no results.

Here's the top of the endless output when running this script, you can kind of see where it gets stuck:

```
Finding forks for repository: OpenROV/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=1
Retrieving forks page 2
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=2
Retrieving forks page 3
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=3
Retrieving forks page 4
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=4
Retrieving forks page 5
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=5
Retrieving forks page 6
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=6
Retrieving forks page 7
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/OpenROV/openrov-software/forks?page=7
Finding forks for repository: labimage/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1
Finding forks for repository: labimage/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1
Finding forks for repository: labimage/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1
Finding forks for repository: labimage/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1
Finding forks for repository: labimage/openrov-software
Retrieving forks page 1
Request string: https://api.github.com/repos/labimage/openrov-software/forks?page=1
...
[goes on forever]
...
```

What did I do wrong? This is my first ever Python question, so thank you in advance for your guidance. Let me know if there are more details I can provide.

Comment: Don't you think it is going on forever because there is no proper base condition?

Comment: @Solen'ya Thanks for your response, but sorry for my ignorant question as someone who is just starting to learn: What do you mean by no proper base condition?

Comment: I had solved a similar type of problem while working with one software. I had to find out the different types of tags (needs another lecture) which are stored in branched folders. The branch structure is not fixed. Folders can hold subfolders and tags. But tags cannot hold folders. This was my base condition. I could find out all the tags irrespective of the folders' structure using this condition. Maybe you need to identify this unique condition that can differentiate the forks from repos and use recursion without using an infinite loop so that the recursion breaks when the end is reached.